# how to communicate two servers with single sessions using servlets

Tags: servlets

I facing a problem while maintaining single session in my servlet, communicating with two servers.
    I am using session.redirect() and session.farward() but i dint get result please help me.

Comment: I do not understan your problem. `session.redirect` does not exist. You should provide some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The "client side" of the two servlets should pass the `JSESSIONID` cookie along on every HTTP request, exactly as a normal webbrowser does. This way the "server side" of the two servlets will be able to obtain the right `HttpSession` object back in the HTTP request/response context.

I have no idea how you're communicating between the servlets, so I can't post a more detailed answer as to how to maintain the session cookie in subsequent requests.

At least, the `session.redirect()` and `session.farward()` makes no utter sense. The [`HttpSession` object](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) does not have those methods. With giving a [`RequestDispatcher` instance](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) the wrong variable name of `session` you also won't help yourself and others much.